# Find difference between two perl nested hashes

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash, set-difference

I'm trying to find difference in two files, that contains key/values entries, and return what all key/values are added or deleted. Currently, I'm using linux `diff` for finding the difference, but its natural that if values orders are changed, then it will be a valid diff, but I don't want to list them, because for me its invalid one.
**file1:**

```
key1    kamal1.google.com kamal2.google.com kamal3.google.com 
key2    kamal4.google.com
```

**file2:**

```
key1    kamal1.google.com kamal6.google.com kamal3.google.com 
key3    kamal4.google.com
```

**What I need:**

- Show `deleted key2 with values kamal4.google.com`, `added key3 with kamal4.google.com`, `deleted kamal2.google.com from key1`, `added kamal6.google.com to key1`
- Message is representational, we can modify it to more meaningful one

**What is my approach:**

- read the files and put in different hashes `key1 => {kamal1.google.com => 1, ...}, key2 => {kamal4.google.com => 1}`. I have taken array also as hash so as we to do diff efficiently.
- Loop over keys of both hash and find if it exists in which hash.
- Make a recursive call to find the diff in values (because its again a hash)

**Problem with my code:**
 - Not working for nesting
 - Lost track of parent.

**Code:**

```
my $file1 = 'file1';
my $file2 = 'file2';

my $old = hashifyFile($file1);
my $new = hashifyFile($file2);
my $result = {};
compareHashes($old , $new, $result);
print Dumper $result;

    sub compareHashes {
        my ($hash1, $hash2, $result) = @_;

            for my $key (keys %$hash1, keys %$hash2) {
                if (not exists $hash2->{$key}) {
                        push @{$result->{deleted}->{$key}}, keys %{$hash1->{$key}};
                } elsif (not exists $hash1->{$key}) {
                        push @{$result->{added}->{$key}}, keys %{$hash2->{$key}};
                } elsif (ref $hash1->{$key} eq 'HASH' or ref $hash2->{$key} eq 'HASH' ) {
                    compareHashes($hash1->{$key}, $hash2->{$key}, $result);
                }
            }
    }

# helper functions
sub trim {
   my $val = shift;
   $val =~ s/^\s*|\s*$//g;
   return $val;
}


sub hashifyFile {
    my $file = shift;
    my $contents = {};
    open my $file_fh, '<', $file or die "couldn't open $file $!";

    my ($key, @val);
    while (my $line = <$file_fh>) {
        # skip blank lines and comments
        next if $line =~ /^\s*$/;
        next if $line =~ /^#/;
        # print "$. $line";

        # if line starts with a word, means its "key values"
        # if it starts with multiple spaces assuming minimum 4, seems values for the previous key
        if ($line =~ /^\w/) {
            ($key, @val) = split /\s+|=/, $line;
        } elsif ($line =~ /^\s{4,}\w/) {
            push @val, split /\s+/, $line;
        }
        my %temp_hash;
        for (@val) {
                # next unless $_;
                $temp_hash{trim($_)} = 1 if trim($_);
        }
        $key = trim($key);
        $contents->{$key} = \%temp_hash if defined $key;

    }

    close $file_fh;
    return $contents;
}
```

Comment: please edit the question and show the expected output from `print Dumper $result`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: After I edited my code, it's giving error, I have not yet fixed. So, I can't give output of `$result`, but I have written what I need. You can call it as smart diff that will show actual diff in two files. Files are no more than 100 lines, so we are free to play with auxiliary arrays or hashes.

Comment: Perhaps something like https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2::Tools::Compare might help?

Comment: @Recct: That module seems to give just boolean value, whether they are equal or not, which is provided by `Data::Compare` as well. But I need actual value. I was exploring `Data::Diff` module, which seems to solve my problem, but would love to go by own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do it based on your description. Please clarify if this is what you wanted.

```
sub compareHashes {
    my ($hash1, $hash2, $result, $parent) = @_;

    my %all_keys = map {$_ => 1} keys %$hash1, keys %$hash2;

    for my $key (keys %all_keys) {
        if (not exists $hash2->{$key}) {
            if ( defined $parent ) {
                push @{$result->{deleted}->{$parent}}, $key;
            }
            else {
                push @{$result->{deleted}->{$key}}, keys %{$hash1->{$key}};
            }
        } elsif (not exists $hash1->{$key}) {
            if ( defined $parent ) {
                push @{$result->{added}->{$parent}}, $key;
            }
            else {
                push @{$result->{added}->{$key}}, keys %{$hash2->{$key}};
            }
        }
        else {
            if ((ref $hash1->{$key} eq 'HASH') and (ref $hash2->{$key} eq 'HASH') ) {
                compareHashes($hash1->{$key}, $hash2->{$key}, $result, $key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'added' => {
                       'key3' => [
                                   'kamal4.google.com'
                                 ],
                       'key1' => [
                                   'kamal6.google.com'
                                 ]
                     },
          'deleted' => {
                         'key2' => [
                                     'kamal4.google.com'
                                   ],
                         'key1' => [
                                     'kamal2.google.com'
                                   ]
                       }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to achieve. I started to pass parent key, but was getting stuck somewhere. I'll test it with various scenario and update my code if there is any need. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several modules on [CPAN](https://metacpan.org) which compare deeply nested data structures.  They differ mostly in how they encode the differences.  Here's a curated list:

- [Data::Difference](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Difference)
- [Struct::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Struct::Diff)
- [Data::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diff)

Comment: I tried 2nd and 3rd one, `Data::Diff` solved my purpose, but I didn't wanted to use any module.